# WP Genesis Framework - Remove post_content and restructure entry

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm creating a Wordpress theme with Genesis.

1.In homepage and archive page, I want display only featured image and post title. How could I remove post_content in hompage and archive page only. This link: http://my.studiopress.com/snippets/entry-content/ remove all content including when I view the post.

2. By default, Genesis display title -> post_info ->featured image -> post_content in the archive page. How could I restructure it. I would to display featured image fist ->title->post_info

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Hiding the Entry Content from Home & Archive Pages in Genesis:

You are on right track with entry_content hook via remove_action however as you want to happen it only on Homepage or Archive pages, you need to wrap that genesis code in WordPress's template tags i.e

```
<?php
if (is_front_page() || is_home() ||  is_archive() ) {
  //* Remove the post content (requires HTML5 theme support)
  remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
 }
?>
```

#### 2.  Changing the Order of Entry Parts in Genesis Framework

You can change order by changing Hooks or if hook is same then WordPress's hook priority value. Default value is 10 , higher the value, lower the hook placement.

For Example Entry Info and Entry Title are added this way:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
```

As you can see title's hook is default 10, and info is set to 12.
If I wanted to move post info up, I could simple remove title from 10, and add back at 14 e.g.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title', 14 );
```

Now you can do change something from lower hook to above. Like in case of image, it is added at this hook:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
```

As genesis_entry_content hook is way lower than genesis_entry_header, you can remove this image from here and move to genesis_entry_header or different hook e.g.

```
 remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
 add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
```

Above code removes Post image from the content section and then adds back to header section above the title.

See this visual guide for order of different genesis hooks: https://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/